# Get the text before and after strstr in C

Tags: c, string, char, strstr

I need to be able to extract the characters before and after a substring, currently I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   char *text = (char *) malloc (10000000);
   char *word = argv[1];
   int rep;

   FILE *f;

   if(argc < 2)
   {
       printf("Usage: GET <website> | ./word_counter <word>\n");
       exit(1);
   }

   fread(text, 100, 10000000, stdin);

   const char *tmp = text;

   f = fopen("output.txt", "w");
   fprintf(f, "%s\n", "REPS");

   while(tmp = strstr(tmp, word)){
      printf("%.50s\n", tmp);
      rep++;
      tmp++;
   }

   printf("Word count: %d\n", rep);
   fclose(f);
   system("gedit output.txt");

   return 0;
}
```

I made a copy of the original input so I could leave it untouched and get the "before" characters from it.

Using strstr() on tmp (the original input copy) I can find the instances of the word I'm looking for and print the first 50 characters. But knowing this, how can I access the 50 characters BEFORE this instance?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As `tmp` is just a pointer, `tmp-50` will point exactly to 50 characters before it. (Do test if that is still within your data.)

Comment: By the way, currently you don't get "the 50 characters after the string" because this count includes your search string as well. Add `strlen(word)` to `tmp` before printing.

Comment: Just checking - did you see my answer? Does it help? If not, what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the printing question itself, there are a couple of errors in your code. I have corrected most of them; a short list is:

1. *Always* test if `malloc` succeeded.
2. `fread(text, 100, 10000000, ..)` reads way too many text. `100 * 10000000 = 1000000000`, almost a full gigabyte. You only allocated enough memory for 10 Mb.
3. You read from a text file and treat this data as a string. Therefore, you must make sure the data ends with a `0`, else functions such as `printf` and `strstr` will try to continue reading after the end.
4. Your `rep` variable starts out uninitialized and therefore you will always see a random number.
5. Always free memory you allocated.

That said, it is slightly more efficient to use a dedicated function to print out text – if only to not put too much in your `main`. And since it's a function, you can add as many useful parameters into it as you want; I added `before` and `after` variables, so you can vary the number of characters shown.

For added niceness, this function prints a correct number of spaces when the phrase is found before the minimum number of `before` characters, so the results line up nicely. Also, since printing out characters such as tab and newlines will mess up your output, I replaced them with `?`.

There is, admittedly, some repetition in `print_range` but in this case I went for clarity, rather than brevity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH  10000000

void print_range (char *source_text, int startindex, int before, int after, int phrase_length)
{
    int i;

    if (before > startindex)
    {
        for (i=0; i<before-startindex; i++)
            printf (" ");
        startindex = before;
    }

    for (i=0; i<before; i++)
    {
        if (strchr ("\t\r\n", source_text[startindex-before+i]))
            printf ("?");
        else
            printf ("%c", source_text[startindex-before+i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<phrase_length; i++)
    {
        if (strchr ("\t\r\n", source_text[startindex+i]))
            printf ("?");
        else
            printf ("%c", source_text[startindex+i]);
    }
    for (i=0; i<after; i++)
    {
        if (!source_text[startindex+phrase_length+i])
            break;
        if (strchr ("\t\r\n", source_text[startindex+phrase_length+i]))
            printf ("?");
        else
            printf ("%c", source_text[startindex+phrase_length+i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *text = (char *) malloc (MAX_LENGTH);
    char *word = argv[1];
    int rep = 0;

    if (!text)
        return -1;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
         printf("Usage: GET <website> | ./word_counter <word>\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    fread(text, 1, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);
    text[MAX_LENGTH] = 0;

    const char *tmp = text;

    do
    {
        tmp = strstr(tmp, word);
        if (!tmp)
            break;
        print_range (text, tmp-text, 16,16, strlen(word));
        rep++;
        tmp++;
    } while (1);

    free (text);

    printf ("Word count: %d\n", rep);

    return 0;
}
```

Result of running this on its own source code:

```
~/Documents $ ./wordcounter printf < wordcounter.c
tindex; i++)????printf (" ");???starti
-before+i]))????printf ("?");???else??
"?");???else????printf ("%c", source_t
before+i]);??}??printf ("{");??for (i=
rtindex+i]))????printf ("?");???else??
"?");???else????printf ("%c", source_t
tindex+i]);??}??printf ("}");??for (i=
_length+i]))????printf ("?");???else??
"?");???else????printf ("%c", source_t
length+i]);??}??printf ("\n");?}??int 
argc < 2)??{??? printf("Usage: GET <we
?free (text);???printf ("Word count: %
Word count: 12
```